# Connecting to dataverse from SQL studio Mangement

Tags: powerapps, power-platform, dataverse

I have just installed Power Platform CoE Starter Kit. I want to see the content of different tables through Microsoft Studio Management c18.8. However I get following error. Any pointers why this does not work?

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you try SQL4CDS in XrmToolBox and verify this behavior?

Comment: I have been on the page for 15 mins now and cant find a link to click on? How do you get the tool?